# How do I increase the number of shortcuts allowed in admin menu?

Tags: routes, users

The number of shorctuts is limited to 7 (second row)

[image]

When I add an 8th shortcut it is in the disabled section

[image]

How do I change that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum number of shortcuts is defined in [`shortcut_max_slots()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!shortcut!shortcut.admin.inc/function/shortcut_max_slots/7), which just returns a variable:

```
return variable_get('shortcut_max_slots', 7);
```

So all you need to do is change that variable to something larger than 7. You can use the devel variable editor to do it, or just run the following code from somewhere:

```
variable_set('shortcut_max_slots', 10);
```

Comment: Simply change modules/shortcut/shortcut.admin.inc, line 16

Comment: @RayHulha Hacking core when there's a trivial override like in the above example isn't the best advice

Comment: Good point, although I consider it a bug fix ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to this Drupal core issue thread: [Remove the default limit of 7 shortcuts per shortcut set](http://drupal.org/node/682000). There's a patch there to completely remove the limit.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to update the shortcut_max_slots variable is actually through [drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) (assuming that you are using it). The command is:

```
drush vset shortcut_max_slots number
```

For example, I did:

```
drush vset shortcut_max_slots 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by adding the following code to your settings.php in sites/default/files/ to increase max number of shortcuts to a preferred value.

/*
 Configuration option to set max number of shortcuts on the shortcut bar
*/
$conf['shortcut_max_slots'] = 20;

source - https://api.drupal.org/comment/34883#comment-34883